# Response::download -> Error 500

Tags: laravel-4, http-headers, content-type, laravel-routing, download

In **Laravel 4.0**, I'm trying to create a (forced) download link for a pdf which is located in `public/assets/files/cvde.pdf`

---

**The view:**

```
<a href="curry/cvde">deutsch</a>
```

**The route:**

```
Route::get('curry/{file}', 'HomeController@downloadCV');
```

**The controller method:**

```
public function downloadCV($file) {
    return Response::download(public_path() . '/assets/files/' . $file . '.pdf', array(
            'Content-Type'=>'application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Disposition'=>'attachment; filename="' . $file . '.pdf"'
        )
    );
}
```

I'm getting an 500-error and the browser points to `public/curry/cvde`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, did you manually check if the file is accessible? secondly I believe your request is wrongly formatted:

```
/**
     * Create a new file download response.
     *
     * @param  SplFileInfo|string  $file
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  array   $headers
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse
     */
    public static function download($file, $name = null, array $headers = array())
    {
            ....
    }
```